# How can I ignore autocomplete with a keyboard shortcut in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, keyboard-shortcuts, autocomplete

Let's say you type the following in Column A Row 1:

`1| Brown Fox`

Now you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

If you type just `Brown` into Column A Row 2, you'll get autocomplete (assuming you haven't disabled it):

`1| Brown Fox`
`2| Brown`**`Fox`**

But let's say you don't want `Fox` in there, just `Brown`. How can you move down to the next row without having `Fox` put in the cell?
I'm looking for a keyboard solution; no mouse involved. Preferably a single key combination. Note that I do not want to disable autocomplete altogether.

I have tried using CTRL/Alt/Shift combinations with <kbd>Enter</kbd> but to no avail.

I'm using excel 2010, but hopefully there's a solution for all versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll notice that the autocompleted part of the text is still selected.

By simply pressing <kbd>Delete</kbd> that text will be deleted. Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> now will normally exit the cell.

This solution works for all versions.

Comment: HA! I was hoping for an `Enter` related hotkey but that is simple enough, funny that I couldn't come up with that myself. Derp.

Comment: I have the inverse request:https://superuser.com/questions/1493572/autocomplete-with-excel-with-any-data-in-the-same-column if you have an idea @LPChip?