# Autocomplete with Excel with any data in the same column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, autocomplete

Let's say you have 3 lines in a column: `abc`, `def`, `hgi`.

- If the cursor is in the next line, and you start writing <kbd>a</kbd>, auto-completion is offered, which is handy
- If there is an empty line, and you start writing <kbd>a</kbd>, no auto-completion is offered!

**How to always enable auto-completion with any value of the same column, no matter if there are blank lines or not?**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, you cannot. Excel does not offer that. You need to have content in between in order for this to work. You can of course put a space or even a ` in that empty cell to fill it with content for this to work though, optionally colouring it white.

Comment: Thank you. Just about the end of your answer what do you mean by coloring white? Is it an alternate method than filling with ` ?

Comment: Coloring a cell with white foreground makes it invisible even if it contains text. This means you can put something in such as #skip and use conditional formatting to automatically set it to white.